# ¿Cómo hacer un filtro de acción personalizado?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Al hacer un get hacia un controlador de mi aplicacion el cual me hace un `return View()` necesito evaluar que ciertas cosas se cumplan antes de renderizar la vista. Para ello decidí en crear un filtro de accion `ActionFilterAttribute` pero tengo las siguientes inquietudes.

El método o la anulación del método heredado debe ser `void` el problema es que necesito que si no se cumple la validación me retorne hacia otra vista, por ejemplo que me haga un `returm View("404")` para redirigirme hacia una vista de error 404.

¿Cómo puedo anular el metodo de accion para poder devolver un ActionResult y no un void?

Esqueleto de mi filtro

```
public async override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // Logic
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes establecer el `Result` de la respuesta y luego redirigir a la

```
public async override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{ 
  // tu lógica y si falla establecer lo siguiente
  filterContext.Result = new HttpStatusCodeResult(404);

}
```

Y configurando tus errores personalizados en el `web.config` ya lo tendríamos

```
<customerrors mode="On">
  <error statuscode="404" redirect="~/Testing/NoPageFound">
 </error>
</customerrors>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias !.